# Errors in Eclipse and Android activity can't seem to figure it

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-construction

I keep getting errors trying to implement a couple of OnLongClick buttons. Eclipse keeps telling me to "add unimplemented methods". I'm very new to developing and I'm asking for some help. :D What am I doing wrong here? This community helped me out before and as soon as I get to where I can give back I will. I thank you all for it. Here's my code for a simple app I'm working on.

```
    package com.kc.eas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RemoteViews.ActionException;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass;

import com.admob.android.ads.AdManager;
import com.admob.android.ads.AdView;

public class act2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AdManager.setTestDevices(new String[] { 
                AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR, 
                "HT089HL01612",
        });

        AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
        adView.requestFreshAd();



        ImageButton batteryhistory = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.battery_history);
            manageservices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent batteryhistoryintent = new Intent(); 
            batteryhistoryintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            batteryhistoryintent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.battery_history.BatteryHistory");
            startActivity(batteryhistoryintent);

        ImageButton batteryusage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.battery_usage);
            manageservices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent batteryusageintent = new Intent(); 
            batteryusageintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            batteryusageintent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.fuelgauge.PowerUsageSummary");
            startActivity(batteryusageintent);

        ImageButton batteryinfo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.battery_info);
            batteryinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent batteryinfointent = new Intent(); 
            batteryinfointent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            batteryinfointent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.BatteryInfo");
            startActivity(batteryinfointent);

        ImageButton manageapps = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.manage_apps);
            manageapps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent manageappsintent = new Intent(); 
            manageappsintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            manageappsintent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.ManageApplications");
            startActivity(manageappsintent);

        ImageButton manageservices = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.manage_services);
            manageservices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent manageservicesintent = new Intent(); 
            manageservicesintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            manageservicesintent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.RunningServices");
            startActivity(manageservicesintent);

        ImageButton radioinfo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_info);
            radioinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent radioinfointent = new Intent(); 
            radioinfointent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            radioinfointent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.RadioInfo");
            startActivity(radioinfointent);


        private WifiManager wifiManager;



        ImageButton startwifiButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.wifi);
            startwifiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            WifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                WifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Disabling WiFi";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

            }else{
                WifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Enabling WiFi";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show(); 
            }

        private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;


        ImageButton bluetoothbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth);
            bluetoothbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            {

            if (enabled) {
                bluetoothAdapter.enable();

            } else {
                bluetoothAdapter.disable();
            }


            //OnLongClickButtons//



        ImageButton bluetoothbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth); 
            bluetoothbutton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
            public void onLongClick(View v) {
            Intent btintent = new Intent(); 
            btintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            btintent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings");
            startActivity(btintent);

        ImageButton wifisettings = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.wifi);
            wifisettings.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public void onLongClick(View v) {
            Intent manageservicesintent = new Intent(); 
            manageservicesintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            manageservicesintent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
            startActivity(manageservicesintent);
                       }
       });
    }
}

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go and hover over the class name

and click "Add unimplemented methods", like shown below

[image]

The reason for the error is that you have used some abstract classes, and its a necessary obligation to give a body to the unimplemented methods from the implemented classes

Comment: Did everything else look okay though? I've been using the Android Cookbook to learn this, but actually doing it is a bit harder than reading.

Comment: yeah it looks ok, If you followed my steps you can see that onLongClick and onClick are implemented inside the class body. You can remove the functions from outside the class body.

Comment: Thanks, Reno. With your help I managed to correct the problem. I love Stackoverflow.com.